# Name Error when getting variable from another define function to be read in another define function in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm not sure how to solve the problem I have encountered, how do I solve this?

**My python code I'm using:**

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as FF
import numpy as np
from datetime import date,time,datetime
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readcsv(x): #def function to read csv files based on input below
    Data = pd.read_csv(x, parse_dates=['Time_Stamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    Data['Date'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.date 
    Data['Time'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.time 

    Data['Time_Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['Time_Stamp']) 
    print(Data[1:6])

readcsv('MainD.csv')

def selTimestamprange(dtStart, dtEnd, Data):
        timestamprange = (Data['Time_Stamp'] > dtStart) & (Data['Time_Stamp'] <= dtEnd)
        TimeRange = Data.loc(timestamprange)
        TimeRange.plot(x='Time_stamp', y='AC_Input_Current', style='-', color='black')

date_string_start = '2017-06-13 16:00:00'
date_string_end = '2017-06-13 16:40:00'
dtStart = datetime.strptime(date_string_start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dtEnd = datetime.strptime(date_string_end,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

selTimestamprange(dtStart, dtEnd, Data)
```

**My Error:**

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        10 #print(type(dtStart)) <-- check if dtStart has been converted to datetime type
>        11 
>   ---> 12 selTimestamprange(dtStart, dtEnd, Data)
>
> NameError: name 'Data' is not defined

Comment: `Data` is local variable in `readcsv` and `selTimestamprange` functions, so you cannot use outside those functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Data` is local variable which is only available in function `readcsv(x)`, you could return it  in the function and assign the result to variable `Data`, then you can use the variable `Data`. Like this:

```
def readcsv(x): #def function to read csv files based on input below
    Data = pd.read_csv(x, parse_dates=['Time_Stamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    Data['Date'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.date 
    Data['Time'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.time 

    Data['Time_Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['Time_Stamp']) 
    print(Data[1:6])
    return Data

Data = readcsv('MainD.csv')
```